# AWS EC2 ubuntu server unable to send emails using SMTP

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, smtp

I have enable the security groups for SMTP but changes are not saved accordingly henceforth the telnet is not responding for the SMTP PORT that was the reason mail is not getting triggered.

- I got the error like this:-
- 2021-05-08 15:39:06 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP
  d22sm14940947pjr.2 - gsmtp    2021-05-08 15:39:06 CLIENT -> SERVER:
  EHLO sahugroups.com    2021-05-08 15:39:06 SERVER -> CLIENT:
  250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [XX.X.XXX.XX]250-SIZE
  35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
  OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-
  ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
  2021-05-08 15:39:06 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN    2021-05-08
  15:39:06 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6    2021-05-08 15:39:06
  CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]    2021-05-08 15:39:06 SERVER
  -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6    2021-05-08 15:39:06 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]    2021-05-08 15:39:07 SERVER -> CLIENT:
  534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?
  sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbt534-5.7.14 vbJf9sV-
  y5OfvF9xzzkuLFaIHVrFmK_HqS0AOXauJsjP6FVOwQv66xX8rdnW7PjP999xD534-5.7.14
  DParKZxs9_2mV4hZyqHvMpZsjeGOiod6gQpJGJ4h_60sGV8IUAUcwIa8tka1YIcf>534-5.7.14
  Please log in via your web     browser and then try again.534-5.7.14
  Learn more at534 5.7.14
  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 d22sm14940947pjr.2 -
  gsmtp    2021-05-08 15:39:07 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed:
  534-5.7.14
  <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbt534-5.7.14
  vbJf9sV-
  y5OfvF9xzzkuLFaIHVrFmK_HqS0AOXauJsjP6FVOwQv66xX8rdnW7PjP999xD534-5.7.14
  DParKZxs9_2mV4hZyqHvMpZsjeGOiod6gQpJGJ4h_60sGV8IUAUcwIa8tka1YIcf>534-5.7.14
  Please log in via your web     browser and then try again.534-5.7.14
  Learn more at534 5.7.14
  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 d22sm14940947pjr.2 -
  gsmtp    SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.    2021-05-08 15:39:07
  CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT    2021-05-08 15:39:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221
  2.0.0 closing connection d22sm14940947pjr.2 -    gsmtp    SMTP connect() failed.
  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting    Mailer
  Error: SMTP connect() failed.
  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
- security groups are not saving properly it has save twice when I changed the configuration from custom to anywhere.

3.get connection timeout while doing telnet
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGwst.png